# No Android SDK found - Android Studio - Missing SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am a beginner in android development. I have installed Android Studio but when I start Android Studio it shows "No Android SDK found" screen every time.

Please guide me if I miss anything during installation.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly check path of SDK in Settings. Verify your path where you have installed SDK

Comment: Goto Tools -> SDK Manager  and check the path of SDK. If it is showing wrong path then give it the actual path. If you have not downloaded SDK then download it from this link and give it the location of installation folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, check the SDK path like others state in comments, by going to: File -> Project Structure -> SDK location

[image]

If your path is correct, check if your downloaded SDK version matches what you are using in project, you can find it in your app gradle file:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  targetSdkVersion 26.0.2
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try to make `Build -> Clean Project` and `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Answer (score 0):

The SDK folder was empty for `C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Android\SDK`

For displaying hidden AppData or Local subfolder: Tools, Folder Options, View, Advanced Settings, Files and Folders, select option Show hidden files, folders, and drives.

The SDK folder should contain the following subfolders:

- `build-tools`
- `emulator`
- `extras`
- `patcher`
- `platforms`
- `platform-tools`
- `sources`
- `tools`

Downloaded the zip file to create the tools subfolder from link, `sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip` of section, Command line tools only, Platform Windows within URL, https://developer.android.com/studio Zip file name: `sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip` Copied this zip file into `C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Android\SDK` Unzipped this file, which created tools subfolder.

Downloaded zip file to create the platform-tools subfolder from the link, Download SDK Platform-Tools for Windows, within URL, https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html Zip file name: `platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip` Copied this zip file into `C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Android\SDK` Unzipped this file, which created `platform-tools` subfolder.

Open Android Studio and follow prompts. Other subfolders will be created automatically.