# How to fix not found SDK in Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I develop one application into **Android Studio** and when close and open Android Studio. 
When open android studio I see red lines with of android studio and **not found SDK** and I can't write any code!

My Android studio error image :

[image]

How can I fix it? please help me

Comment: is your [SDK path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path) set properly ?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil, I check project structure and show me my SDK! why show me such as above image?

Comment: which os you use for this mac, ubuntu or window?
please change your android studio setting once and setup your sdk path and setting  or clean and build one and two time. 
i hope it help you

Comment: Did your Gradle build successfully ?

Comment: @Vijendrapatidar, yes my dear friend. first I develop on Mac and my system is Windows. when open into windows show me this errors. on mac not show me any error! I clean project and rebuild project but not fix again. how can I fix it? can you help me? please my friend please

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil, yes dear friend I sure. please help :( please read above my friend and then help me. please

Comment: delete your auto generate build files and rebuild again.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982265/no-android-sdk-found-android-studio-missing-sdk) help?

Comment: @Vijendrapatidar, how can I delete this? where is here? can you help me. because I am amateur, thanks

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil, no my friend. i'm bad lucky :(

Comment: @Vijendrapatidar,  can you help me my friend? pleaseee :(

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling the studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Delete this all four folder's and rebuild again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQK85.png)`and also check your local.properties file "sdk.dir=/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk"`

[image: Please check your sdk path and also check your local.properties file "sdk.dir=/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk"]

Comment: in `local.properties` show me my SDK location on windows! why show me this error??? :(((((((((((

Comment: @WoW.j Delete this all four folder in your build folder and rebuild again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project:

Tab Build -> Clean Project